# Type mismatch in typescript and react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have an issue with typescript and react. Bellow is a small exmaple that illustrates the problem.

```
const Example = (props: { x?: number, fn: (x: number) => void}) => {
        if (props.x !== undefined) {
            return <button onClick={() => props.fn(props.x)}>Click me</button>
        }
        return null;
}
```

Code checks explicitly that x is defined but typescript won't compile it because fn requires x to be a number. It can be solved using casting

```
const y = props.x as number;
return <button onClick={() => props.fn(y)}>Click me</button>
```

It works but looks weird. Any ideas how to handle such cases. It's just an example in my code we have an object instead of a number and it also either defined and then we render some html for it or not defined (=== undefined) and than we just return null.

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation in how control flow analysis works. The analysis does not cross function boundaries. You can read more [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998). The basic idea is that there is no guarantee `prop.x` will still not be `undefined` by the time the callback is called.

The workaround is to put `prop.x` in a local variable. This will capture the flow type in the variable type:

```
const Example = (props: { x?: number, fn: (x: number) => void}) => {
        if (props.x !== undefined) {
            const x = props.x
            return <button onClick={() => props.fn(x)}>Click me</button>
        }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works, now it looks better, still a bit strange but at least no casting.

Comment: the point is that this is callback. in time of call your x can be theoretically undefined.

Comment: @JurajKocan 10x, added to the answer, I was being lazy, good thing SO community keeps me honest 